# Use Dictionary from another folder in XAML UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

this is the content of my dictionary [Dictionaries/myDictionary.xaml]:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:myApp/Dictionaries"
    xmlns:media="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Media">

    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="myAcrylicBrush"
            BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
            TintColor="#202020"
            TintOpacity="0.8"
            FallbackColor="#202020"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And here is where I need to use it [Pages/myPage]:

```
<Page
    x:Class="myApp.Pages.myPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:myApp.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:animations="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- Here it gives me error -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Dictionaries/myDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource myAcrylicBrush}"/>
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="gridPrincipale" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

I've tried

> Source="pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Dictionaries/myDictionary.xaml"

but it doesn't work…

Both folders "Dictionaries" and "Pages" are in the Project's folder.

Answer (score 0):

For UWP you'll want to use the `ms-appx` location for the Souce.

Example:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Company.Themes/Dictionaries/myDictionary.xaml" />
```

Where `Company.Themes` is the project name, and `Dictionaries/myDictionary.xaml` is the location of the resource file from the root of the project